# How to use Options pattern to bind Json value as a string from appsettings.json file

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

Im building a Web-Api. How do I use the Options pattern to bind a json string value from my appsettings.json. The value in my appsettigs.json file is an escaped json string as shown below (this has to be a json string).

The formatted Json that is saved as a string in my appsettings.json file looks like this

```
 [
    {
        "Item": "Bread",
        "Code": "Br"
    },
    {
        "Item": "Milk",
        "Code": "Mk"
    }
]
```

**My appsettings.json file** with escaped json string

```
{

    "MappingCodes": {
        "SystemOne": "[{\"Item\":\"Bread\",\"Code\":\"Br\"},{\"Item\":\"Milk\",\"Code\":\"Mk\"}]"
    }

}
```

I have a **MappingCode.cs** class (to bind the json string) and a **Product.cs** class (to represent json string value)

```
public class MappingCode
{
    public string SystemOne{ get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Item{ get; set; }
    public string Code{ get; set; }
}
```

How do i inject a collection of the Product class from the StartUp class so im able to use it something like this

```
public class MyClass
{
   public MyClass(IOptions<IList<Product>> products){
   {
      var prods = products.Value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your startup (or program if you use)

```
services.Configure<MappingCode>(configuration
                    .GetSection("MappingCodes"));

services.AddScoped<MyClass>();
```

and code

```
public class MyClass
{
   private readonly List<Product> _products;

    public MyClass(IOptions<MappingCode> mappingCode)
    {
        _products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(mappingCode.Value.SystemOne);
    }
}
```

if you turn escape string into string in appsettings, you will not need  to deserialize, so I recommend

```
"MappingCodes":{"SystemOne":[{"Item":"Bread","Code":"Br"},{"Item":"Milk","Code":"Mk"}]}
```